# Rake test error - ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" by MICHAEL HARTL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm following the book "Ruby on Rails Tutorial" by MICHAEL HARTL, are in Section 8 and I implemented several TEST. Now when you launch bundle exec rake test get 26 errors and I can not understand what is not good.

```
ERROR["test_invalid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_invalid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (1432285939.41s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:           ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_valid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_valid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (1432285939.42s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_password_should_have_a_minimum_length", UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_password_should_have_a_minimum_length#UserTest (1432285939.43s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_email_addresses_should_be_saved_as_lower-case", UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_email_addresses_should_be_saved_as_lower-case#UserTest (1432285939.43s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:           ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses", UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_email_validation_should_accept_valid_addresses#UserTest (1432285939.43s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_name_should_not_be_too_long", UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_name_should_not_be_too_long#UserTest (1432285939.44s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_password_should_be_present", UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
 test_password_should_be_present#UserTest (1432285939.44s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError

 ERROR["test_authenticated?_should_return_false_for_a_user_with_nil_digest",  UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_authenticated?_should_return_false_for_a_user_with_nil_digest#UserTest (1432285939.45s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_email_addresses_should_be_unique", UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_email_addresses_should_be_unique#UserTest (1432285939.45s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_email_should_be_present", UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_email_should_be_present#UserTest (1432285939.46s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_email_should_not_be_too_long", UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_email_should_not_be_too_long#UserTest (1432285939.46s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_name_should_be_present", UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_name_should_be_present#UserTest (1432285939.46s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_should_be_valid", UserTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_should_be_valid#UserTest (1432285939.47s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_login_with_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]    
 test_login_with_remembering#UsersLoginTest (1432285939.47s)
ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


 ERROR["test_login_without_remembering", UsersLoginTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
 test_login_without_remembering#UsersLoginTest (1432285939.48s)
 ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


 ERROR["test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout", UsersLoginTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
 test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout#UsersLoginTest (1432285939.48s)
 ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


 ERROR["test_should_get_new", UsersControllerTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
 test_should_get_new#UsersControllerTest (1432285939.49s)
 ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


 ERROR["test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil", SessionsHelperTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil#SessionsHelperTest (1432285939.50s)
  ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


 ERROR["test_current_user_returns_nil_when_remember_digest_is_wrong", SessionsHelperTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
   test_current_user_returns_nil_when_remember_digest_is_wrong#SessionsHelperTest (1432285939.50s)
  ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


 ERROR["test_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
  test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (1432285939.51s)
  ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


 ERROR["test_should_get_new", SessionsControllerTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
  test_should_get_new#SessionsControllerTest (1432285939.52s)
 ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


 ERROR["test_should_get_contact", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
  test_should_get_contact#StaticPagesControllerTest (1432285939.52s)
 ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_should_get_help", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
  test_should_get_help#StaticPagesControllerTest (1432285939.53s)
  ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
  test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (1432285939.53s)
 ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_should_get_about", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
 test_should_get_about#StaticPagesControllerTest (1432285939.54s)
 ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError


ERROR["test_full_title_helper", ApplicationHelperTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:19 +0200]
 test_full_title_helper#ApplicationHelperTest (1432285939.54s)
 ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError
```

These are the test file:

Users.yml

```
michael:
name: Michael Example
email: michael@example.com
password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

User Session Controller Test

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
   test "should get new" do
     get :new
    assert_response :success
   end
 end
```

Thank you all for the help!

---

> I edited the file User.yml and now the errors are only the following:

---

```
FAIL["test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil", SessionsHelperTest, 2015-05-22 11:12:20 +0200]
  test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil#SessionsHelperTest (1432285940.28s)

  --- expected
  +++ actual
  @@ -1 +1 @@
    -#<User id: 762146111, name: "Michael Example", email: "michael@example.com", password: nil, created_at: "2015-05-22 22:13:21", updated_at: "2015-05-22 22:13:22", password_digest: "$2a$04$PvQxwZgXnhi9RxICezCHJuQRRkUiSoP9qjPixSvx8mb...", remember_digest: "$2a$04$obYQeBWrZ59amJ9Ey2nd6.r8aeD.2h14uiEGB1XpywS...">
    +nil
    test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'
```

Sessions Helper Test

```
require 'test_helper'
class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase

  def setup
    @user = users(:micheal)
    remember(@user)
   end

  test "current_user returns right user when session is nil" do
    assert_equal @user, current_user
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

  test "current_user returns nil when remember digest is wrong" do
    @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(User.new_token))
    assert_nil current_user
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your fixtures have some bad formatting. The fixtures are loaded before the tests, and if something is wrong you'll get the error "ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError: ActiveRecord::Fixture::FormatError". This appears for each test since each test is dependent on the fixtures.

In YAML, indentation is significant. In your Users.yml file you need to add a little indentation, like this:

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Comment: Ok, now the errors sono stati reduced to three, very well, I do not know why I have not noticed the fall, Because I Googled this error and I Realized That it was a formatting error but I had read it was That Caused by the space after:, and my was. However I added new errors above. Thanks for the help

Comment: I think I understand, I added the user Micheal to the database  and now only one error, place above.

Comment: @LucaVasapolli Looks like you have just one test failure. Apparently `current_user` is returning nil, but the expectation is that it should be equal to `@user`. Look back through the tutorial to make sure you didn't miss any code need to make the `current_user` method work.

Comment: I corrected the error, I called twice function current_user, thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It seems your fixture file is with wrong formatting.

`Users.yml`:

```
michael:
  name: Michael Example
  email: michael@example.com
  password_digest: <%= User.digest('password') %>
```

Try to ident the attributes.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the help, the main error was just that, now they were only three.